# Is it possible to delete CWM backups without CWM

Tags: adb, samsung, backup, clockworkmod-recovery

Previously I have installed CWM as my recovery but then I have flashed the stock rom back. CWM was removed as a result and I can no longer access CWM. I am trying to delete all the backups I made. Ideally I don't want to reinstall CWM.

I tried to find the location of the backups and I came across `/mnt/shell/emulated/clockworkmod/backup`. Is it safe to remove the files in this directory with adb? Or is there a better way to do it?

`/mnt/shell/emulated/` seems to contain a copy of the old files which is different than `/mnt/sdcard/`.

Note that this is on Samsung Galaxy S3 which the version of the CWM is fairly old.

Comment: For some reason my question is downvoted without any reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  They are just files and can be deleted as normal.

There are probably several symlinks and aliases on your device that all point to `/mnt/sdcard/`, nothing to worry about there.